# The same array has different lengths?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Can someone please explain to me, because I don't understand something here, why the same array has two lengths? I assume I understand something wrong here, it must have the same length, right? 
I have this call:

```
    console.log(eventsBeforeRender);
console.log(eventsBeforeRender.length);
```

and in browser console i see this:
[image]

What I want to achieve, is to access the element [0] of the root array, so then from this element I can access other elements, of which from what I see there should be 17.
Calling this:

```
console.log(eventsBeforeRender[0]);
```

returns undefined.

Comment: hover over the blue `i` ... that should explain it - clearly `eventsBeforeRender` array is filled asynchronously

Comment: thank you,  I added sleep function and I got result. I think it would be nice to find another way around this than putting sleep function tho.

Comment: @JaromandaX I used setTimeout

Comment: Fair enough, that's definitely the very last thing you want to do. As I said, learn how to use asynchrony